# Outlook add ins are not shown on metered connection

Tags: office365, outlook-addin, office-js, office-addins

We have an important customer who are facing an issue where our add in is not shown when they are on a metered connection (Their laptops have in built LTE connection)

We are not able to toggle the setting for metered connection on Windows 10, through either the settings or through MS Intune (due to a MS restriction).

Could you please suggest a way to make the add ins show up consistently for this situation?

Comment: Hi, Can you please mention on which platform is this happening? [Web, Windows Client or Mac]